# PHP scandir and relative path

Tags: php, scandir

I've tried all the solutions I read on here but can't seem to get this to work.

I'm trying to call scandir in this file:
https://www.example.com/cms/uploader/index.php

to list all the files and directories in this folder:
https://www.example.com/uploads/

I don't want to hardcode the example.com part because this will be different depending on the site.  I've tried many combinations of: dirname(**FILE**), **DIR**, $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], and $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], etc.  I either get a "failed to open dir, not implemented in..." error or nothing displays at all.  Here is the code I'm using:

```
    $directory = __DIR__ . '/../../uploads';
    $filelist = "";
    $dircont = scandir($directory); 
    foreach($dircont AS $item) 
    if(is_file($item) && $item[0]!='.')
    $filelist .= '<a href="'.$item.'">'.$item.'</a>'."<br />\n";
    echo $filelist;
```

What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: Just use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],  $directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/uploads';

Comment: Tried it, but there's no output and no error log. The problem may be elsewhere. Do I need to add a directory here somehow: if(is_file($item) && $item[0]!='.') ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $directory variable is set wrong. If you want to go 2 directories up use dirname() like this:

```
$directory = dirname(__DIR__,2) . '/uploads';
$filelist = "";
$dircont = scandir($directory);

foreach($dircont AS $item) {
    if(is_file($item) && $item[0]!='.')
        $filelist .= '<a href="'.$item.'">'.$item.'</a>'."<br />\n";
}


echo $filelist;
```

You can read more about [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) there is a section on how to use it with urls if allow_url_fopen is enabled but this is mainly in local/development environment.

Comment: When I echo out $directory, the path looks right, but no files are being listed. I'm wondering if there's an issue with my if statement? EDIT: Yes, when I remove the if statement the files are listed, I think I can figure it out from here, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i am not able to write a comment to ask you a question( low reputation ).

As far as i understand from your explanation, you wanted to add possible folder names to make your probe in a way will work automatically.

If yes, then i would do such piece of code like this;

```
$website = 'http://localhost/';
$folders = array('uploads','files', 'uploads/files');

$filelist = "";

foreach ($folders as $kinky) 
$dircont = scandir($website.$kinky);
foreach ($dircont AS $item)
    if (is_file($item) && $item[0] != '.')
        $filelist .= '<a href="' . $item . '">' . $item . '</a>' . "<br />\n";

echo $filelist;
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I only need the contents of this directory: example.com/uploads. I tried your code, but it doesn't work.  I get the following errors: [09-Feb-2019 20:00:36 UTC] PHP Warning:  scandir(http://localhost/uploads): failed to open dir: not implemented in /home/public_html/cms/uploader/index.php on line 123
[09-Feb-2019 20:00:36 UTC] PHP Warning:  scandir(): (errno 2): No such file or directory in /home/public_html/cms/uploader/index.php on line 123
[09-Feb-2019 20:00:36 UTC] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/public_html/cms/uploader/index.php on line 124